# How does hide()/show() system works? fragment android

Tags: android, fragment, hide, show

after some research i need to implement hide() and show() system on my app,

now I'm doing this way:

When i select some fragment to show on my menu, i create with new Fragment(), then i use beginTransaction().replace() to replace the content on my FrameLayout with this new Fragment...

But i need to don't recreate this fragment, and i think, use the hide() and show() system, but, how do i implement this? how exactly hide() and show() works? do i need to use backstack and so?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had tried the hide/show mechanism of FragmentManager. There below is one segment of my source codes implementing this. Have a look:
This method to hide all visible and non-null Fragments:

```
private void hideAllFrags(FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    for (String name : fragNames) {
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
        if (fragment != null && !fragment.isHidden()) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment);
        }
    }
}
```

And then, the key method is here:

```
{
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    hideAllFrags(fragmentTransaction);
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            if (fragA == null) {
                fragA = new FragA();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_container, fragA, fragNames[0]);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragNames[0]);
            } else {
                fragmentTransaction.show(fragA);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            if (fragB == null) {
                fragB = new FragB();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_container, fragB, fragNames[1]);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragNames[1]);
            } else {
                fragmentTransaction.show(fragB);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I hope this will help you;)

Comment: PS:if detecting the life span of the two Fragment, you would have found that, when hide/show was called, no methods of life span of Fragment is called. That means the method of hide/show just make the root view of relative Fragment gone(invisible)/visible.